# An exercise in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be (positive) measure space with $\mu(X)=1$. Let $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^m\subseteq M$ such that almost every $x\in X$ belongs to at least $n$ of these sets ($1\leq n\leq m$). Prove $\mu(E_i)\geq\frac{n}{m}$ for some $1\leq i\leq m$.

First thing I did was partition $X$ into $m$ disjoint sets $X_k$ with $X_k$ is the set of all $x\in X$ such that $x$ belongs to exactly $k$ of these sets. Then assume $\mu(E_i)<\frac{n}{m}$ for all $1\leq i\leq m$. How to deduce a contradiction from this?

Comment: sum the characteristic functions and integrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start: The condition that almost every $x\in X$ belongs to at least $n$ of the $E_i$ amounts to the statement that $\sum_{i=1}^m\chi_{E_i}\ge n$, $\mu$-a.e. (Here, $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$.) Integrating with respect to $\mu$ we get 
$\sum_{i=1}^m\mu(E_i)\ge n$.